# What value in my heading is hiding the content on the rest of the page?

Tags: html, css, header, navbar

I have a heading and navbar with a workaround hamburger menu (no javascript).  However, there is something in the code that means that whenever I try to write anything below it .. text.. place an image etc, it doesnt show.

Curiously, if I set
`body {background-color: red;}`
that works, but I cant use the body as a reference as it will be a multipage site.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*global styles */

/* Header styling */

header a {
  color: black;
}

.header {
  background-color: #ffe8d6;
  font-family: "cabin", 'serif';
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}

/*menu styling*/

.header ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #ffe8d6;
}

.header li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ffe8d6;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header li a:hover,
.header .menu-button:hover {
  background-color: #c8b6ff;
}

.header .skillshare {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header .menu {
  clear: both;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height .2s ease-out;
}

.header .menu-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding: 28px 20px;
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
}

.header .menu-icon .nav-icon {
  background: #333;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  position: relative;
  transition: background .2s ease-out;
  width: 18px;
}

.header .menu-icon .nav-icon:before,
.header .menu-icon .nav-icon:after {
  background: #333;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
  width: 100%;
}

.header .menu-icon .nav-icon:before {
  top: 5px;
}

.header .menu-icon .nav-icon:after {
  top: -5px;
}

.header .menu-button {
  display: none;
}

.header .menu-button:checked~.menu {
  max-height: 240px;
}

.header .menu-button:checked~.menu-icon .nav-icon {
  background: transparent;
}

.header .menu-button:checked~.menu-icon .nav-icon:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.header .menu-button:checked~.menu-icon .nav-icon:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.header .menu-button:checked~.menu-icon:not(.steps) .nav-icon:before,
.header .menu-button:checked~.menu-icon:not(.steps) .nav-icon:after {
  top: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 48rem) {
  .header li {
    float: left;
  }
  .header li a {
    padding: 20px 30px;
  }
  .header .menu {
    clear: none;
    float: right;
    max-height: none;
  }
  .header .menu-icon {
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <header class="header">
    <a href="index.html" class="skillshare">Skill Share</a>
    <input class="menu-button" type="checkbox" id="menu-button">
    <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-button">
    <span class="nav-icon"></span></label>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="events.html">Events</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>`
    </ul>
  </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the header has `position: fixed;`, the following content is hidden beneath it. Try this :

```
body {
 padding-top: 60px; //adjust 60 to your liking, just make sure it's higher than header height
}
```